# Struggling to link dynamic SQL statements together without error

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

```
DECLARE @overview TABLE(
    category VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @overview
SELECT DISTINCT category
FROM table_3

DECLARE @temp_table TABLE(
    category VARCHAR(100),
    increment IDENTITY(1,1)
)

INSERT INTO @temp_table
SELECT DISTINCT category
FROM table_1

DECLARE @cursor INT
SET @cursor = 2

DECLARE @cursor_max INT
SET @cursor_max = (
    SELECT MAX(increment)
    FROM @temp_table
)

DECLARE @top_cat VARCHAR(100)
SET @top_cat = (
    SELECT TOP(1) category
    FROM @temp_table    
)

DECLARE @select_module NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @select_module = CONCAT(
    'subfunction, [',@top_cat,']'
)

DECLARE @join_module NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @join_module = CONCAT(
    '
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT SUM(table_2.totals) [',
        (SELECT @top_cat,'],
        table_2.description
        WHERE table_2.category = ',
        (SELECT @top_cat),'
        GROUP BY table_2.description
    ) AS join_',@cursor,'
    ON join_',@cursor,'.description = oo.function'
)

WHILE @cursor <= @cursor_max
BEGIN
    SET @select_module = CONCAT(
        @select_module,', [',(SELECT category from @temp_table WHERE increment = @cursor),']'
    )
    SET @join_module = CONCAT(
        @join_module,'
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT SUM(table_2.totals) [',
            (SELECT category from @temp_table WHERE increment = @cursor),'],
            table_2.description
            WHERE table_2.category = ',
            (SELECT category from @temp_table WHERE increment = @cursor),'
            GROUP BY table_2.description
        ) AS join_',@cursor,'
        ON join_',@cursor,'.description = oo.function'
    )
    SET @cursor += 1
END

DECLARE @instruction NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @instruction = CONCAT(
    'SELECT ',@select_module,'
    FROM ',@overview ,'oo
    ',@join_module
)

EXEC sp_executesql @instruction
```

The code above gives the following errors:

> Must declare the table variable "@overview". 
> Incorrect syntax near 'Line'. 
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'. 
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Full'.

I think the errors are coming from string formatting, but I can't place where any mistakes are. I'm trying to join multiple columns onto the table @overview, using the @cursor and while loop to iterate through @temp_table to find the columns to join, and then the @select_module, @join_module, and @instruction to build the final statement. Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Try to print variable @instruction and other. When you get result copy it to another tab and try to execute. Step by step and I think that will solve your problem.

Comment: A look at your SQL, and there's a lot that doesn't make sense, For example you define `@overview` as a table type variable, but in places try to reference the **scalar** variable `@overview`. You have  subqueries which don't close their parathesis; for example `(SELECT @top_cat,'],` (why is that not just `@top_cat` anyway?). It's also open to injection as syntax like `'[' + {expression} + ']'` does not safely escape values; you should be using `QUOTENAME`. You need to take a step back here and explain what you are really trying to achieve as the SQL above is littered with errors.

Comment: I see a few mistakes: @temp_table doesn't have a data type for increment (identity isn't a data type). As mentioned by others, `@join_module` has mismatched open and close parenthesis, particularly at the first (SELECT `@top_cat`; additionally, unsure why there's a select there. That is messing up the WHILE loop. get through these and then print your statement, as Marko mentioned and you should see what your other issues may be

Comment: wrt. `Must declare the table variable "@overview".` `sp_executesql` will be executing `@instruction` in its own scope so it won't see the `@overview` table. Consider converting that to a connection-specific temp table, `#overview`. Also, instead of trying to quote your own tokens with `[` and `]` use the [QUOTENAME()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) function.